# Using listings, how do I maintain grouping of listing numbers?

Tags: latex, listings, lstlisting

I'm using the `listings` package for showing code, as well as algorithms in pseudocode.

This is what I would like happen:

```
Algorithm 1.1: myFirstAlgorithm()
    ... content ...
Algorithm 1.2: mySecondAlgorithm()
    ... content ...
Code 1.1: My First Code Block
    ... content ...
Algorithm 1.3: myThirdAlgorithm()
    ... content ...
```

While this is what I get:

```
Algorithm 1.1: myFirstAlgorithm()
    ... content ...
Algorithm 1.2: mySecondAlgorithm()
    ... content ...
Code 1.3: My First Code Block
    ... content ...
Algorithm 1.4: myThirdAlgorithm()
    ... content ...
```

To change the caption name, I'm using `\renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{Code}` and `\renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{Algorithm}`.

There might be a better way to do this, but in any case I'm still clueless as to how to reset the numbering, or how to keep track of grouping. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly advise against changing the numbering. Having one numbering for all objects in your manuscript makes it much easier for the reader to find things. I have a maths book with Theorem 3.6 followed by Lemma 3.2 followed by Exercise 3.6 followed by Remark 3.1 and it's very hard to find anything, because you have to search for objects of the same type, before even looking at their numbers. With a single numbering scheme, you could "binary search" much easier.

Comment: You might be right. I assumed the reader would find it intuitive to sort the pseudo-code separately from the general code. The same way as I have a different set of numbering for figures, tables, equations.

Comment: I'll have to agree with Thomas. I find it much easier navigating the various listings in a book when they're all ordered by the same sequence.

Comment: Fair enough :) I'll bow to the will of general consensus. However, if anyone knows a solution, I'd like to know. If only to enable it and reminisce on what could've been. *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spite of my comment above, here's some code to create two new environments, `algorithm` and `code`, that do what you ask for.

```
\newcounter{oldlstlisting}
\newcounter{algorithm}[chapter]
\newcounter{code}[chapter]

\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[1][]{
    \setcounter{oldlstlisting}{\value{lstlisting}}
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{algorithm}}
    \renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{Algorithm}
    \lstset{#1}
}{
    \stepcounter{algorithm}
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{oldlstlisting}}
}
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]{
    \setcounter{oldlstlisting}{\value{lstlisting}}
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{code}}
    \renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{Code}
    \lstset{#1}
}{
    \stepcounter{code}
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{oldlstlisting}}
}
```

Usage:

```
\begin{algorithm}[caption={myFirstAlgorithm()}]
    ... content ...
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[caption={mySecondAlgorithm()}]
    ... content ...
\end{algorithm}

\begin{code}[caption={My First Code Block}]
    ... content ...
\end{code}

\begin{algorithm}[caption={myThirdAlgorithm()}]
    ... content ...
\end{algorithm}
```

These number by chapter, as you probably intended, and are numbered independently of "regular" `lstlisting` environments. Furthermore, you can specify additional `\lstset` arguments (e.g. `language=...`) in the environment definition, if you want.

---

Update: To use the same numbering for all of them, just remove all counter-related code:

```
\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[1][]{
    \renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{Algorithm}
    \lstset{#1}
}{
}
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]{
    \renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{Code}
    \lstset{#1}
}{
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. Some day I need to fully understand latex environments and the subtleties. First I need to finish my thesis. I'll heed your advice though, and be critical to the of multiple listing counters. Have a good day, Sir.

Comment: And it works perfectly! If I want to use the same numbering, I use the same counter in both environments. My relationship with latex was initially filled with hate and contempt. Now there is no longer any hate. I wish I could express my gratitude with other things than words, but alas: thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :) But if you want to use the same numbering, no need to mess with counters at all. See my update.